# SELECT JSON_VALUE From table returns null instead of value

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, json-value

JSON stored in a column 'DataJson'  in table

```
[{
    "KickOffDate": "1-Jan-2019",
    "TeamSize": "11",
    "ClientEngineer": "Sagar",
    "WaitingPeriod": "16.5"
}]
```

Query

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(DataJson,'$.KickOffDate') AS KickOffDate
     , JSON_VALUE(DataJson,'$.ClientEngineer') AS ClientEngineer
FROM [ABC].[Deliver]
```

Result

```
KickOffDate   ClientEngineer
NULL          NULL
```

Result should be:

```
KickOffDate   ClientEngineer
1-Jan-2019    Sagar
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  If not, then please tell us your database.

Comment: Firstly look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name A Google search for `"JSON_VALUE SQL"` seems to bring up only SQL Server stuff.

Comment: MICROSOFT SQL SEVER

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: so I am supposed to search the internet to find the correct DBMS? And besides: JSON_VALUE is part of the SQL standard and Oracle,  DB2 and  MariaDB also support JSON_VALUE.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Don't look at me, I just work here! :P

Answer (score 12):

Your sql query is wrong.
You have to correct query like below.

```
 SELECT JSON_VALUE(DataJson,'$[0].KickOffDate') AS KickOffDate ,JSON_VALUE(DataJson,'$[0].ClientEngineer') AS ClientEngineer FROM [ABC].[Deliver]
```

The data stored in table is not JSON Object, it's JSON Array.
So in order to get each value of JSON Object, need to set index of JSON Object in JSON Array.
Otherwise, you can store data as JSON Object, and then your query can be work normally.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON appears to be malformed, at least from the point of view of SQL Server's JSON API.  From what I have read, if your JSON data consists of a top level JSON array, then the array needs to have a key name, and also the entire contents should be wrapped in `{ ... }`.

The following setup has been tested and works:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '{ "data" : [{"KickOffDate": "1-Jan-2019", "TeamSize": "11", "ClientEngineer": "Sagar", "WaitingPeriod": "16.5"}] }' AS DataJson
)

SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(DataJson, '$.data[0].KickOffDate') AS KickOffDate,
    JSON_VALUE(DataJson, '$.data[0].ClientEngineer') AS ClientEngineer
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Here is what the input JSON I used looks like:

```
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "KickOffDate": "1-Jan-2019",
            "TeamSize": "11",
            "ClientEngineer": "Sagar",
            "WaitingPeriod": "16.5"
        }
    ]
}
```